# When do team managers submit the batter lineup to the umpire?

Tags: baseball

## Background

I am interested in looking at the matchups between the pitcher and the batter lineup he has to face.  However, there are several times I have looked at the batting lineup for a game beforehand (even day of) and have only seen "TBD" with no expected time. Per the question on [announcing probable pitchers](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/10297/15951) it is said that team managers submit the lineup to the umpire. From there it is then displayed. But the one unknown for me is...

## Question

Is there a customary time when the manager submits the batting lineup to the umpire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only officially done a few minutes prior to the beginning of the game.  Some managers will (unofficially) release a lineup (or announce changes to an established lineup) to the media well ahead of a game.  However, such a release doesn't bind the team.  The manager may make changes to the lineup until the official presentation without penalty.

According to [MLB Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/documents/0/8/0/268272080/2018_Official_Baseball_Rules.pdf):

> 4.03 Exchange of Lineup Cards
>
> Unless the home club shall have given previous notice that the game has been postponed or will be delayed in
> starting, the umpire, or umpires, shall enter the playing field **five
> minutes before the hour set for the game to begin** and proceed directly
> to home base where they shall be met by the managers of the opposing
> teams. In sequence:
>
> (a) First, the home manager, or his designee,
> shall give his batting order to the umpire-in-chief, in duplicate.
>
> (b) Next, the visiting manager, or his designee, shall give his batting
> order to the umpire-in-chief, in duplicate.
>
> [...]
>
> (d) The umpire-in-chief shall make certain that the original and
> copies of the respective batting orders are identical, and then tender
> a copy of each batting order to the opposing manager. The copy
> retained by the umpire shall be the official batting order. **The tender
> of the batting order by the umpire shall establish the batting orders.
> Thereafter, no substitutions shall be made by either manager**, except
> as provided in the rules.